# Not getting selected event when eventsWillOverlap is true

Tags: ios, swift, calendarkit

I am using Calenderkit (https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit)in my project.

I am unable to get selected event obj data in delegate method when eventsWillOverlap is true.

getting correctly if eventsWillOverlap is false.
below is the code I tried

```
    open func dayViewDidSelectEventView(_ eventView: EventView) {
    print("Event has been selected: \(eventView.descriptor)")
     }
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, add the full code you're using with the CalendarKit. Would be great, if you could create a sample project that could help troubleshoot this issue.